# prevent login after incorrect password 5 times

Tags: login

I made custom login page with open sources. 
I want to set the times of login password false(?). I mean.. when user insert his password in login page and that is incorrect password, I want to prevent to try to login with same username after 5 times incorrect password. This is for user-security. Is there a way to prevent from trying to login with same username more than 5 times incorrect password? 
sorry for not good English expression. And thank you.

Comment: Have you check any of the [existing implementations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts-reloaded/)?

Comment: How have you made the custom login page?

Comment: this is not an effective way to prevent brute force attacks, as they are coming from many IPs and likely to randomally check different users. In addition this kind of strategy will make it easy for an attacker to prevent an actual user from logging in. The best defense is to force good passwords.

Comment: I made custom login page by googling, haha.

Comment: //Mark kaplun. there are some ineffectives. But when I made profile page usgin username(this included in url), I need to protect username.